# How do I get Data into an Iphone application from a URL Using the UIWebView?

Tags: iphone

I have an application that I am working on that uses UIWebView.  I'm not much of a Web Wonk so I am not familiar with what is probably a trivial task- How do I pass data back to my application when I load a web site?  The site is on a server that passes a google map to the application but I also need some additional information passed along with it. I would think this is simple. Where do I start to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to use a UIWebView. Instead look at `NSURLRequest` to download the HTML source for a page.

Comment: Is the purpose of NSURLRequest to allow variables to be passed to a web application?

Answer (score 0):

Well, what sort of information is it?

If it is text, you could suck the text down in XML or some other mechanism, and then dynamically build your HTML page, then pass that to the UIWebView.

If it is image data, you could do the same with data: urls, it's a little tricky but it can be done.

If you just need to load the web page into the webview, there is a method for that in the UIWebView initializers.

Comment: I am looking to send a couple of points along with the google map.  Just text- no images

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
document.location = something you'll recognise containign the coords.
```

And then handle

```
webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
```

in UIWebViewDelegate, do whatever you want and return NO. You can also use a url scheme which your app recognises, but I haven't explored that approach yet.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly what your asking, and your coordinates were: `-34.603687,-58.381616` you should use:

```
    NSString *encodedStringWithCoordinates = @"-34.603687%2C-58.381616" //The comma URLEncoded is %2C... You can encode your string with NSUTF8StringEncoding or whatever...

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?q=%@", encodedStringWithCoordinates]];

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webview loadRequest:requestObj]; //Your UIWebView is webview i suppose
```

If you need help with enconding just tell me.

EDIT: I thought this was a new Q, i would leave the answer because it may help someone.